# How to print "/" in report name odoo 14?

Tags: odoo-14

I want to download quotation with the name Quotation number as "SQ/001" but it prints "SQ_001". How to remove this underscore and print as it is in sale.

code:

```
print_report_name="(object.state in ('draft', 'sent') and 'Quotation - %s' % (object.name)) or 'Sale Order - %s' % (object.name)"
```

Comment: have you tried escaping that? // like this

Comment: Yes. It is printing double underscore.

Comment: I'm sorry.. It should be backslash. Like this \/?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see,your issue is strange. Because while creating a file manually in Linux OS, it won't allow you to use these special symbole, I am not sure about the Windows OS. But normally "/" is not allowed as a valid character in file name.
So Odoo internelly replace it with "_" to avoid file name error.